# NGRX Effect throws Error Type XXXX not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I want to get the latest data from the state and make a service call to the backend.I created the below effect for that

```
onboardGuest$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe( 

      ofType(GuestActions.onboardGuest),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectGuest)),
      switchMap(([{reqPayload}]) => {
        return this.httpClient.post(environment.urls.guestOnboard, reqPayload).pipe(
          switchMap(({payload}) => {
               return GuestActions.onboardGuestSuccess({resPayload:payload})
          }),
          catchError((err) => {
            return of(GuestActions.onboardGuestFailure({ error: err }))
          })
        )
      })
    );
  });
```

but in the second switchMap, I have this error.what am I doing wrong here

```
Argument of type '({ payload }: Object) => { resPayload: any; } & 
TypedAction<"[Guest] Onboard Guest Success">' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object, 
index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.

Type '{ resPayload: any; } & TypedAction<"[Guest] Onboard Guest Success">'
 is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.

Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '{ resPayload: any; } & 
TypedAction<"[Guest] Onboard Guest Success">' but required in type 'Iterable<any>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you should use just `map` instead of `switchMap` because you are just transforming the sync event to sync something, not to observable

```
map(({payload}) => {
     return GuestActions.onboardGuestSuccess({resPayload:payload})
}),
```

Comment: the issue I mentioned above is resolved by your example.if I want to access the value return by the `this.store.select(selectGuest)` and use the values to the service call how should I do that.because i am getting `reqPayload` via action payload.i want avoid action payload.

Comment: If I got everything right, you should save just the payload in your store inside of your reducer, not the whole action